# spring mvc path variable missing

Tags: spring-mvc

I am using Spring MVC, and I have a url request as:
http://localhost:8080/address/getAddress/latitude=112.08&longitude=38.23

And my method is as:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "getAddress/latitude={latitude}&longitude={longitude}")
public @ResponseBody AddressResponse getAddress(@PathVariable double latitude, @PathVariable double longitude){
    //my codes
}
```

But when I debug, the longitude is 38.0 instead of 38.23. Whatever longitude I entered, number after "." is always missing. I enter 38.28374, it comes out 38.0, I enter 29.87789, it comes out 29.0. Why this happens? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Could you try with a pattern: `{longitude:\\d+[.]\\d+}`?

Comment: Are you able to get the correct value (i.e., 112.08 for latitude ? Can you also try to explicitly mention the path variable to bind to as @PathVariable("longitude")

Comment: @BalajiKatika : latitude is correct, I can get 112.08 for latitude. For `@PathVariable("longitude")`, do you mean `public @ResponseBody AddressResponse getAddress(@PathVariable double latitude, @PathVariable("longitude") double longitude){}`?

Comment: Can you try with getAddress?latitude={latitude}&longitude={longitude} Note the ? after the getAddress

Comment: @sp00m your solution resolved my question. But I am sorry I don't know how to rise your comment as best answer.

Comment: @BalajiKatika I still get 38.0 instead of 38.28374 of longitude as your suggestion. But thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "getAddress/latitude={latitude:.+}&longitude={longitude:.+}")
```

will fix the issue. Normally nothing will be processed after the dot. This syntax will also accept values with dot.